# Writing an api call to create a User Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am really stuck for hours now.

I have the following UserSerializer:
UserModel = get_user_model()

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user


    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'deliveries', 'password')
```

And this as my view:

```
class UserList(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, 
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am using the standard Django User Model. But I am not able to sent out a http req. to create a user. I always get "400_BAD_REQ"

My request in httpie looks like this:

```
http -v POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/user-list/ username="Rudy" password="12345"
```

With other models I do not have these problems. Can someone tell me why this is not working?

EDIT: As Shakil wrote the problem really was with the specified fields but even when declaring read_only fields it does not work as expected.

**Does not work**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = UserModel.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user

class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('id', 'deliveries', 'username', 'password')
    read_only = ('id', 'deliveries',)
    write_only = ('password',)
```

**This does work:**

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = UserModel.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user

class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('username', 'password',)
```

**Deliveries is a PrimaryKeyRelatedField.**

Comment: do you add any custom validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only passing `password` and `user_name` to the serializer but you include others field like `id` and `deliveries` too.

```
class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'deliveries', 'password')
```

whatever you field you include you must need to pass them otherwise `ModelSerializer` will rise validationError.

```
class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'deliveries', 'password')
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'deliveries')
    write_only_fields = ('password')
```

as `password` is always a write_only field and also i am supposing `id` and `deliveries` are your read_only field ( you are not always suppose to pass them to serializer)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I edited my original post slightly to dig a little deeper into the problem. Any ideas on why the POST req. does not work when declaring the fields read_only?

Comment: what is your version of DRF ?

Comment: i am really sorry, i did a typo mistake.  `read_only_fields` and `write_only_fields` should be included , not `read_only` and `write_only`. sorry for that.

Comment: Ah, alright - this solves it. Only one small addition. While looking in the docs (and wondering why the hashed password was return as an http response I saw that write_only_fields does not seem to exist (anymore?). Now it is: extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}